# Arduino base 2 calculator not working C++

Tags: c++, arduino

This is my code for an Arduino, I think the problem is the input(//nr1 and //nr2) because it worked before changing it to its current state. Thank you for helping in advance!

```
int nr1 = 0;
int nr2 = 0;
int rs = 0;

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  pinMode(2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(3, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(4, OUTPUT);

  pinMode(9, INPUT);
  pinMode(10, INPUT);

  pinMode(11, INPUT);
  pinMode(12, INPUT);
}


void loop()
{
  //nr1  
        if(digitalRead(11)==LOW && digitalRead(12)==LOW)
       {
          nr1 = 0;
       } else if(digitalRead(11)==LOW && digitalRead(12)==HIGH)
       {
          nr1 = 1;
       }  else if(digitalRead(11)==HIGH && digitalRead(12)==LOW)
       {
          nr1 = 2;
       }  else if(digitalRead(11)==HIGH && digitalRead(12)==HIGH)
       {
          nr1 = 3;
       }

  //nr2
       if(digitalRead(9)==LOW && digitalRead(10)==LOW)
       {
          nr1 = 0;
       } else if(digitalRead(9)==LOW && digitalRead(10)==HIGH)
       {
          nr1 = 1;
       }  else if(digitalRead(9)==HIGH && digitalRead(10)==LOW)
       {
          nr1 = 2;
       }  else if(digitalRead(9)==HIGH && digitalRead(10)==HIGH)
       {
          nr1 = 3;
       }

  //rs
       rs= nr1 + nr2;



          if(rs>4)
          {
             digitalWrite(2, HIGH);
          }else
          {
            digitalWrite(2, LOW);
          }

          if(rs%4==2)
          {
             digitalWrite(3, HIGH);
             digitalWrite(4, LOW);
          } 
          if(rs%4==1)
          {
            digitalWrite(3, LOW);
            digitalWrite(4, HIGH);
          } 

          if(rs%4==0)
          {
            digitalWrite(3, LOW);
            digitalWrite(4, LOW);
          }

          delay(1000);

nr1=0;
nr2=0;
rs=0;
}
```

Comment: I highly recommend taking a snapshot of `digitalRead` and storing into a temporary variable.  Each time you execute `digitalRead()`, you could return a different value (which kind of screws up your present comparison scheme).  Also read up on the keyword `volatile`.

Comment: If you convert the results of `digitalRead()` into 1 or 0, you can determine `nr1` by using math, thus eliminating the `if-else-if` ladder.

Comment: Your //nr2 section  reassign nr1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your loop, you never assign `nr2` a value.
Maybe you want this:

```
const unsigned int pin9 = (digitalRead(9) == LOW) ? 0 : 1;
const unsigned int pin10 = (digitalRead(10) == LOW) ? 0 : 1;
nr2 = pin10 << 1 | pin9;
```

The above code fragment reads pin 9 and 10 **once**, converts them into a one or zero, then calculates `nr2` based on the values of pin 9 and 10.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to assign the digitalRead values ​​to a variable and use it within the ifs, this will cause you to read the digital pin value previously, start by trying something like `state12 = digitalRead (12);` and inside the if do something like

```
if (state12 == HIGH)...
```

Comment: And you can try too it:  ```if((digitalRead(11)==LOW) && (digitalRead(12)==LOW)){
...
}```